# How does Realm for Android actually store data?

Tags: android, orm, realm

I am looking at migrating a native Android project from an SQLite database to an ORM. I have considered what I believe to be the fastest current contenders - DBFlow (based on SQLite) and Realm.

Therefore, out of curiosity, does anyone know what sort of data format Realm is using? Having read their documentation, this is seems to be a pretty closed subject and I could not find anything on the matter.

Comment: https://realm.io/news/jp-simard-realm-core-database-engine/ Here is an simple introduction of Realm's underlying storage engine. It might be helpful a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their site - Realm is not an ORM on top of SQLite. Instead it uses its own persistence engine and their source code is open for java. 
https://github.com/realm/realm-java

Comment: Your answer does not addresses the OP's question

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more?